Creating JetAppointments Without a Date Picker Using URL
I’m currently working on a project where I’m using JetAppointments to handle appointments on a website. However, I need to create appointments without the user manually picking a date from a date picker. Instead, I want to dynamically fill the date based on a timestamp (or something else) passed in the URL.
Has anyone implemented something similar before, or can point me in the right direction to ensure this will work smoothly?
Thanks in advance for any tips or insights!
